# Validating kid in azure jwt token by hard coding the kid

Tags: javascript, node.js, jwt, azure-active-directory

I am getting a azure token and to verify I was checking the **kid** in header by decoding this token from jwt.io and then I hardcoded the kid in my code for future tokens.

Now, after some days the public keys has been changed and the previous kid which I stored in my code is outdated and not matching from the ***https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/discovery/keys***.

Can any one help how can I add the kid in my code to verify the token or if I can decode the header of the token directly and verify the kid from ***https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/discovery/keys***.

Comment: Do you have any other concerns?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to decode the Azure AD JWT token in node application, we can use the package [`jwt-decode`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jwt-decode).

For example

```
const jwt_decode = require("jwt-decode");

const token =
  "eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGc...";

const res = jwt_decode(token, { header: true });
console.log(res);
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks Jim, I got the idea from your answer.